# How to create 2D Polygon with C#

Tags: c#, plot

I am trying to create this 2D polygon but I get a blank a image after plotting the points.
The Point class takes x and y axes as parameters. Point(x, y)

[image]`

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 800, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 2);
Point[] points =
{
    new Point(2408,  919),
    new Point(2596, 919),
    new Point(2596, 1200),
    new Point(2408,  919),
    new Point(2596, 1505),
    new Point(2572, 1505),
    new Point(2408,  1200),
    new Point(2408,  919)
};
graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, points);
bitmap.Save("DrawPolygon.png");
```

Update: The polygon now displays as per Jimi's first comment. New issue is the polygon shortest length always sit on the horizontal axis and the polygon lines are crossing.

Comment: Aren't all those points outside the Bitmap bounds? What if you increase the Bitmap size to, say, (3000, 2000)?

Comment: I feel so stupid now but thanks

Comment: Right, but you should also consider that your axes are inverted so you probably need to use `TranslateTransform` to rotate the world coordinates, or use a translate Matrix. -- Also, you cannot plot in any order, or you get lines that cross the polygon. You need to order your points (e.g., middle-in, or middle-out)

Comment: Jimi. Could you provide an answer for this? I added the details so the question captures it

Comment: To answer what question? About the mismatched size of the Bitmap? All of it, including my observations? Another one: the values in X don't have the same scale as the value in Y. The polygon's going to be distorted drawn as it is.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, please